# Forgot SSIS Pipeline executed

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, etl, pipeline

At work, I executed an SSIS Pipeline between 2 databases on 2 different servers and I left for the weekend because it Was taking too long... Now I'm worried if this will produce an issue or whatever because its in debugger mode
Is it safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why should it be unsafe?! Many ETL jobs are designed to run on weekends.**

The only thing you must worry about is that you should not keep your computer turned on and logged in with your user while you are not at work.